# Magento 2.3.0 URL keys regenerate on import

Tags: magento2.3, import, catalog, url-rewrite, url-key

This is a serious issue that is occurring on numerous Magento 2.3 builds (I have tried)

If we use the import function from a CSV with the "name" header, Magento automatically updates the URL key to match this. If I do not add the "name" header, the URL keys simply delete themselves.

This is incredibly frustrating as it ruins my URL Rewrites. As the URL key updates, the URL rewrites do not. This makes updating products in bulk through the import feature incredibly annoying and damaging.

Is this a bug with 2.3? or simply a setting I've missed? I cannot reproduce this issue on a 2.2 build, nor can I find any solutions online to this problem.

Edit: I'd like to point out that I can regenerate these URL keys from a module, this isn't difficult but it's not an ideal solution.